# Good service for collecting photos from many wedding guests?

Tags: images, file-sharing, photos

Many guests at my wedding took photos with their cameras and telephones. I'd like to get original-quality copies of all those images. Almost everyone has already started uploading them to Facebook, which would be perfect, but it reduces the image quality and the original is not downloadable.

**Is there an easy-to-use service that all my wedding guests can use to send me original-quality copies of their photos?**

I want to make it easy for them all. It can't be too complicated. It should just be browser-based rather than require a desktop application.

Comment: Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://superuser.com/faq). Questions about web apps are considered off topic on Super User. Questions within this scope are better fit on our Q&A website http://webapps.stackexchange.com which is currently in open beta. Your contribution will help it stay alive. - Voting to close

Comment: Okay. Is there a "move question" option?

Comment: not yet.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be for you to create a dummy [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/) account and have everyone log in to it and put their pictures in one folder. You only get 2 GB so I would think you'll need to offload those pictures to another folder on your computer as they arrive. This way, people who feel comfortable can install the application on their computer, while others can use the DropBox web interface to upload files.

Note that I'm not suggesting that everyone gets a DropBox account and adds a shared folder [like usual](https://www.dropbox.com/help/19), but that everyone logs into the same account. Not sure if this is against their policy, but it would be most efficient for a one time transfer from many people.